# How to manually configure the database type for a property in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a class:

```
class Order
{
    public OrderId Id {get;set;}
}

struct OrderId
{
    private int readonly id;

    public OrderId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

For some reason, I don't want to use a primitive type for the property.
When I'm trying to save object of this class to `Sql Server` through `Entity Framework Core`, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Order.Id' is of type 'OrderId' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or manually configure the database type for it.'

Question: Is it possible to configure mapping in such a case and how to do it?

Comment: you might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370104/convert-value-when-mapping

Comment: I don't want to use additional fields either. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Alew You could try specifying an explicit data type, but you'd also need a conversion operator defined, and after all your effort I doubt it'll work.  How will a query look that tries to match on this non-primitive type.  You'll have to `new` up a struct just for specifying query criteria.  Entities need to be pretty close to their DB definition, including matching DB types. It is better to map to a model or use additional properties when needed.  I would really have a sit-and-think on what "some reason" is that you think a primitive type isn't sufficient.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types

Comment: Actually, "some reason" is a set of esoteric concepts like object model purity, primitive obsession and so forth.

Comment: @Alew Unfortunately EF entities aren't pure business model objects.  Often times you'll need entities that represent certain database entities that are necessary for data modelling, but do not represent the true object model.  Sometimes you need to expose complex many-to-many entities with state/status fields or soft delete fields, even though none of that has any place within a pure business model.  A tiered approach will lead you to only deal with those database implementation specific entities/fields in the DB layers, and map EF entities to business models that are passed thru tiers.

Comment: @Alew See the upvoted comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21033341/84206  I also tried to use only EF entities when EF came out and leverage the complex EDMX mapping to massage the data model into a proper business model, but in the end it was not feasible.  It's alot cleaner to let EF entities be a close representation of the database model, and map those to Model classes used in business layers.  It's a choice of how you slice separation of concerns.  I prefer to let EF entities only be concerned with data access and nothing more, and that's what I've seen succeed in large projects.

Comment: Currently not supported. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9194

Comment: @Smit, write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @AaronLS, thanks for your comments. Actually, I tired to do manual model mapping and prefer a little domain model pollution to writing handmade ORM on top of EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported at present in EF Core (upto version 2.0) For tracking issue and possible work-around see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9194