# Is it possible to hide the collection, which defines the relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When defining a many to many relationship EF Core mandates the use of a join class.  I am trying to hide this join class.

In my scenario a Person (entity 1) plays many Sports (entity 2), so there is a PersonSport (entity 3) table.

Using Entity Framework Core I can do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .ToTable("Person")
            .Property(p => p.Surname)
            .HasField("_surname");
```

The class looks something like this:

```
private readonly string _surname;
public string Surname
{
    get
        {
            return _surname;
        }
}
```

EF Core will correctly create a database field for: Person.Surname.  Say the Person table has a relationship with Sport i.e. a Person participates in many Sports.  Therefore there is a junction table called: PersonSport.  Is it possible to do this:

1) Add a readonly collection to the Person table:

```
private readonly List<PersonSport> _personSport;
```

2) Setup the join as follows (in the context):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSport>()
.HasOne<Person>(ps => ps.Person)
.WithMany("_personSport")
.HasForeignKey(sc => sc.PersonId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I am trying to hide the PersonSport list.  The user of the class will use the following instead:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Sport> sports => _personSport.Select(ps=> ps.Sport).ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

Is this possible? When I run: `Add-Migration InitialCreate; the error is`Value cannot be null`.`